# Extract the single value from a 1 x 1 data.frame produced with dplyr as a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, indexing, numeric

I am trying to extract the value from a 1 x 1 data.frame produced with dplyr as a vector

#### Example

Suppose we have

```
library(dplyr)

df <- iris %>% summarise(ifelse(tally(.) == 150, 1, 0))

df
#   n
# 1 1
```

I expected `df[1,1]` to return the desired result `[1] 1` (i.e. a vector), but, instead it returns a matrix.

```
> df[1,1]
     n
[1,] 1
```

#### Notes

- Somewhat strangely, when we create a similar data.frame manually, we ***can*** retrieve the value as a vector with `.[1,1]`

```
> data.frame(n=1) -> b
> b[1,1]
[1] 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the summarise? If you just want a boolean, why do that in summarise?

Comment: @NelsonGon my actual use case is far more involved than the MRE in the question, but basically I want to arrive at a single number output (i.e. vector of length 1) from some lengthy `dplyr` operations. The single value will be used as a parameter in some further operations

Comment: @NelsonGon Actual use case will be a number between `0` and `Inf`

Comment: Problem is as is it seems less clear what is being achieved. Could you expand on the MRE?

Comment: I think it is quite important to know what exactly is your goal. As testing whether a dataset has n rows could be done more efficiently than this.

Comment: @NelsonGon I may have overcomplicated things. Basically the summarise will always produce a single value output (i.e. a 1x1 data.frame). I am having trouble accessing that value (i.e. extracting it from the data.frame). The actual code from my script is `summarise(ifelse(tally(.) == 0, 1, max(team_number) + 1))`. This will return 1 if a person is not already in a team, but `team_number + 1` (i.e. a new team) otherwise

Comment: I think you need to do this grouped by person or teams, get n() and then amend as required. Otherwise using the whole tally is not clear to me. Something like this(should adapt): `group_by(Species) %>% 
 summarise(N=ifelse( n()== 50,n() + 1,0)) %>% 
  pull(N)`

Comment: I think I understand your question and the answer to which would be hidden in docs somewhere but if you know that you will always have 1 X 1 output you could `unlist` i.e `iris %>% summarise(n = ifelse(tally(.) == 150, 1, 0)) %>% unlist(n)`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks, and sorry all for the confusion, `%>% unlist %>% unname` did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the vector using `df[[1,1]]`

> Output

```
> df[[1,1]]
[1] 1
```

> Here is a simple example that explains how it works using test data

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
```

> Output

```
> df1['a']
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
> df1[['a']]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: It works. Can you explain why `[[1,1]]` works but `[1,1]` doesn't?

Comment: The double box-brackets [[]] returns the contents of the data frame element, while single brackets []  returns the data frame element itself.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @sachin's answer, two additional methods may also work

```
df %>% as.numeric
[1] 1
```

and

```
df %>% unlist %>% unname
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but adding a dplyr solution.

```
df_num <- iris %>% 
  summarise(ifelse(tally(.) == 150, 1, 0)) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.numeric()
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `c` + `t` combo can manage it

```
> c(t(df))
[1] 1
```